# For loop on pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, series

I'm trying to implement code that includes a for loop on a list of pandas Series:

```
a = pd.Series(dtype= 'float64')
b = pd.Series(dtype= 'float64')
c = pd.Series(dtype= 'float64')


data = [a,b,c]

for k in data:
    if len(k) < 1:
        k = k.append(pd.Series([1,2]))
        
print(a)


# returns: Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I thought print(a) would return the appended Series containing [1,2]. But it just returned the original empty Series I initially defined. Of course, printing b and c also returned an empty Series. Meanwhile, if I directly do the append instead of using the for loop:

```
a = pd.Series(dtype= 'float64')
a = a.append(pd.Series([1,2]))

print(a)

# returns: 

0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

So the latter method returns the appended Series just fine. Why doesn't this work for the former method? I expected the first method to return the same result as the one in the second method. I thought the local characteristic only applied to defining functions, not for loops. Am I missing something here?

Comment: maybe a typo? `a = a.append(pd.Series([1,2]))` It seems you are mixing variable names around...

Comment: @TitoOrt no the second method works just fine. I don't think there are typos... I wish to know why the for loop (the first method) doesn't do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `append` (and almost all methods of Pandas), you get a "copy" of the Series. The modification is not in place.

Debug with `id`:

```
print(f"a: {id(a)}, {id(data[0])}")

for k in data:
    print(f"k before: {id(k)}")
    if len(k) < 1:
        k = k.append(pd.Series([1,2]))
        print(f"k after: {id(k)}")
    break
```

Output:

```
a: 140711220977520, 140711220977520
k before: 140711220977520
k after: 140710157071840  # <- not data[0], not 'a'
```

**Update**

> One last question, then would the for loop work fine in terms of memory allocation for other objects (besides pandas objects such as Series) where the method doesn't create a new copy of the original variable?

If data contains mutable objects like list, it works:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
data = [a, b, c]

for k in data:
    if len(k) < 1:
        k.append([1, 2])
```

Output:

```
>>> a
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: But since `k.append(pd.Series([1,2]))` was assigned back to `k` in the for loop, doesn't this literally mean `a` is assigned the copy of the `append` and therefore the id of `a` should also be changed to  140710157071840 ? Why is the id of `a` still 140711220977520 after the for loop?

Comment: the second `k` is not the same as the `k` in loop. This is the same name but it references another memory block.

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean... Then am I unable to use the for loop for the pandas series (to get the result I want)? Should I stick to the manual assignments, like `a = a.append(pd.Series([1,2]))`, `b = b.append(pd.Series([1,2]))` and `c = c.append(pd.Series([1,2]))` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. It's not possible to do that. Consider (even if it's not exactly right), Series or DataFrame are immutable.

Comment: I see ... One last question, then would the for loop work fine in terms of memory allocation for other objects (besides pandas objects such as Series) where the method doesn't create a new copy of the original variable?

Comment: It depends on the object types inside `data` if they are mutable or not.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your last question with a sample of mutable object.

Comment: ok, thanks! Your comments were really helpful